# Horizontal alignment of equation and text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I want to make a list of Quantum Mechanics formula like the format of the following picture. But I am confused about how to make the equations align to the left while the text to the right. Usually, if I use environment like, `Align` or `Equation`, the equation will be at the center.

I know I can use `fleqn` package, but it does not align the equations to the left enough as wee see from the picture I attached. My thought to approach this is to use`fleqn`, then put in the `align` environment, then use a bunch of `\qquad` to align for the text part, which is on the right side of the page. But I think this is silly.

Can anyone give me an example of this format? Or does anyone know if there are some cool packages for me to use so that my formula list would look as nice as this one?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use the `flalign*` environment provided by the `amsmath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  &c=\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}=\SI{3e8}{\m\per\s} &&\text{speed of light}\\
  &\epsilon_0=\SI{8.85e-12}{C^2\per \N\m^2} &&\text{permittivity in vacuum}\\
  &\mu_0 =\SI{4\pi e-7}{\N\per\A^2} &&\text{permeability in vacuum}
\end{flalign*}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make the equations more left?

Comment: Do you really mean more left? The equations are already left aligned to the text body.

Comment: I now know what I got confused about. Actually I want the text to look more left, instead of positioning more left on the text body. So, I should change the `margin` to make it look more left on the page.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `align` inside the `amsmath` package. By putting the `&` on the LHS you can left-align your equations. For example, the first three rows of your table are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &c=\frac1{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}=3\times 10^8 m/s &&\text{speed of light}\\
  &\epsilon_0=8.85\times 10^{-12}C^2/Nm^2 &&\text{permittivity in vacuum}\\
  &\mu_0 =4\pi\times 10^{-7}N/A^2 &&\text{permeability in vacuum}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this is basically a table, I would use a `tabular*` with a `\fill` between the columns.  That way, the table will be flush with the left and right margins of the text, which is what the OP seemed to desire.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\boldcal#1{\ooalign{$\mathcal{#1}$\cr\kern.3pt$\mathcal{#1}$}} 
\begin{document}
{\centering FINAL FORMULA LIST\\
\tabcolsep=0em
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l}
$c = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0 \mu_0}} = 3 \times 10^8\,\text{m/s}$ &
  speed of light \\
$\epsilon_0 = 8.85 \times  10^{-12}\,\text{C$^2$/Nm$^2$}$ &
  permittivity in vacuum\\
$\mu_0 = 4\pi \times 10^{-7}\,\text{N/A$^2$}$ & permeabilty in vacuum\\
\textbf{Electrostatics} & \\
$\mathbf{E}(r) = \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \displaystyle\int 
  \dfrac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{\mathcal{R}^2}\dot{\boldcal{R}} 
  d\tau'$ & Coulomb's Law\\
with the notation: & \\
\end{tabular*}
\par\medskip
}
\noindent This text just shows that the above table is left aligned and 
right-aligned to the underlying text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I change the `margin` of the text to make it look more left.